# How to UPDATE a column only once per ip/session?

Tags: php, database, sql-update, hitcounter

I'm trying to make a `hit counter`, but this `hit counter` update the column `counter` every time the page is loaded.

```
$mread = $conn->prepare("UPDATE bn_publicacao SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = :id");
$mread->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$mread->execute();
```

I want it to update the `counter` only once per ip/session. How can i do it?

Comment: you can add a session value with a flag, or `if( empty($_SESSION['update_chk']))`...` then do your query and  `$_SESSION['update_chk'] = 1;`

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @Samuel  Maybe. However, if the OP happens to have declared `$id` as `$id = (int)....;` then it'd be ok.

Comment: I don't think she is casting it as an integer. The OP seems to be checking the IP/Session as the `$id`.

Comment: @Samuel We don't know that since that's all she posted. Please ping back as I did here, I may have left the question which I will be soon.

Comment: @LeoTahk That's what you meant? https://pastebin.com/cjSkg7ZU. Could you give me more details please?

Comment: @Samuel I could use bindParam i guess, I'll solve this later.

Comment: @Natalie yes you can (`bind_param`)

Comment: you will get really inaccurate results doing this, where as using google analytics will give you much more accurate results and a whole lot of other data to boot.

Comment: @IdontDownVote Actually this query is just for a "Most Read" posts.

Comment: i would still use google analytics, let them work out what a unique user is, but  of course your call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();
```

OPTIONAL:
Check if session started.
Here could be a function(s) that set the session config.

```
if(function_exists('session_status')){
   if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)die('no session');
}else{
  die('no session');
};
```

After session has been started and configured, you can use the variables in $_SESSION.

```
   if(empty($_SESSION['counter']))
    {
        $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
        $mread = $conn->prepare("UPDATE bn_publicacao SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE id = :id");
        $mread->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $mread->execute();
    };
```

This way it will run the query code only if the $_SESSION['counter'] does not exist.

this is only example of the counter once per session, not the query.

Comment: **this is only example of the counter once per session, not the query.** what query are you talking about? I raplaced my code code with yours, but the `counter` is still updating, when i reload the page.

Comment: @Natalie you have `session_start();` on the page before any output?

Comment: @Natalie, do `print_r(session_status());` and make sure it returns `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE` or '2'

Comment: @LeoTahk It's working, thanks! Would i care about where to put the `session_start();`? I'm asking it because there's no `session_destroy`. I put the `session_start();` before the `doctype`.

Comment: glad it works, you can start session anywhere, but make sure its before the code that requires session variables. You only need session_destroy() to manually kill the session if some error or different ip or something, normally session will time out on closing the webbrowser.

Comment: Write the session start unconditionally -- there is no benefit in checking first. Most devs will advise you to write the session start as the first line of code in your script.  `die()`is should be discouraged as a matter of best user experience.